# Regex to match pattern with subdomain in java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match the sub domain and domain.
i used this code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "http://aaa.example.com";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("http://([a-z0-9]*.)example.com");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("match");
        }

    }
```

this works for `http://aaa.example.com` and also for `http://aaa.example.commm`. need to match only the sub domain for example.com
UPDATE :
Thanks for the answers and it works now i am facing another issue this regex is not matching `http://example.com`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use matcher.matches() instead of find(). Matches will match the entire region against the pattern.

Comment: This is because your expression should be something like: Pattern.compile("http://([a-zA-Z0-9]*\\.)*example.com").