# Matching subdomain and top domain using regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

Follow up of this question
[Regex to match pattern with subdomain in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393918/regex-to-match-pattern-with-subdomain-in-java)

I use the below pattern to match the domain and subdomain

```
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("http://([a-z0-9]*.)example.com");
```

this pattern matches the following

- `http://asd.example.com`
- `http://example.example.com`
- `http://www.example.com`

but it is not matching

- `http://example.com`

Can any one tell me how to match `http://example.com` too?

Answer (score 1):

Just make the first part optional with a `?`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("http://([a-z0-9]*\\.)?example\\.com");
```

Note that `.` matches any character, you should use `\\.` to match a literal dot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex pattern to get domains of all urls:

```
\\p{L}{0,10}(?:://)?[\\p{L}\\.]{1,50}
```

For example;

```
Input  = http://www.google.com/search?q=a
Output = http://www.google.com

Input  = ftp://www.google.com/search?q=a
Output = ftp://www.google.com

Input  = www.google.com/search?q=a
Output = www.google.com
```

Here, \p{L}{0,10} stands for the http, https and ftp parts (there could be some more i don't know), (?:://)? stands for :// part if appears, [\p{L}\.]{1,50} stands for the foo.bar.foo.com part. The rest of the url is cut out.

And here is the java code that accomplises the job:

```
public static final String DOMAIN_PATTERN = "\\p{L}{0,10}(?:://)?[\\p{L}\\.]{1,50}";

public static String getDomain(String url) {
    if (url == null || url.equals("")) {
        return "";
    }
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(DOMAIN_PATTERN);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(url);

    if (m.find()) {
        return m.group();
    }
    return "";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getDomain("www.google.com/search?q=a"));
}

Output = www.google.com
```

Finally, if you want to match just "example.com" you can simply add it to the end of the pattern like :

```
\\p{L}{0,10}(?:://)?[\\p{L}\\.]{0,50}example\\.com
```

And this will get all of the domains with "example.com":

```
Input  = http://www.foo.bar.example.com/search?q=a
Output = http://www.foo.bar.example.com
```

Note : Note that \p{Ll} can be used instead of \p{L} because \p{Ll} catches lowercase unicode letters (\p{L} all kind of unicode letters) and urls are constructed of lowercase letters.