# Regex to match pattern with subdomain in java gives issues

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match the sub domain of an url using `http://([a-z0-9]*.)?example.com/.*` which works perfectly for these cases.

```
http://example.com/index.html
http://test.example.com/index.html
http://test1.example.com/index.html
http://www.example.com/122/index.html
```

But the problem is it matches for this URL too.
http://www.test.com/?q=http://example.com/index.html

if an URL with another domain has the URL in path it matches.Can any one tell me how to match for current domain only. getting the host will work but i need to match full URL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402111/matching-subdomain-and-top-domain-using-regex-in-java

Comment: Your code has this exact problem: you're missing the \\ in front of the `.`. Use `http://([a-z0-9]*\\.)?example\\.com/.*`

Answer (score 3):

Are you aware that `.` matches any character?

If you use the regex

```
http://([a-z0-9]*\.)?example\.com/.*
```

(or, as a Java String)

```
"http://([a-z0-9]*\\.)?example\\.com/.*"
```

it should work because now the `?q=` part won't be matched.

This assumes that you're using the `.matches()` method which forces the entire string to match. Otherwise, add a `^` at the start of the regex.

Comment: Don't forget to escape the `.` after `example`. I almost missed it as well :)

Comment: Of course +1 for that and also specifying that he needs to use `matches()`

Answer (score 1):

simplest way would be:

```
^http://([a-z0-9]*?\.)?example\.com/.*
```

the ^ matches the starting position within the string. Dont confuse it with [^ ] though.